# Android Studio Electric Eel - The supplied javaHome seems to be invalid. Tried location: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java.exe

Tags: java, android, android-studio, java-home

**Android Studio Electric Eel** - The supplied javaHome seems invalid. I cannot find the Java executable. Tried location: `C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java.exe`

The error occurs after upgrading my Android Studio to Electric Eel,  the latest version. I tried multiple solutions to this problem, but nothing worked.
My JAVA_HOME and ANDROID_HOME variables are set. I even tried to reinstall Java JDK-19 and reinstalled the Android Studio, but I still have the same issue.

I even tried to reinstall Java JDK-19 and reinstalled Android Studio, but I still have the same issue.

Comment: If someone faces this error after the Android Studio update to Android Studio Electric Eel | 2022.1.1 then simply follow the following steps:

Go To the android studio directory (Default C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio) remove jre folder run cmd as administrator

cd C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio mklink /D "jre" "jbr" Thanks to this link

Answer (score 30, accepted):

SOLVED:

For Windows

Go To the android studio directory

(Default C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio)

remove jre folder

run cmd as administrator

```
cd C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
mklink /D "jre" "jbr"
```

Comment: thank you , its worked can you please explain what is happening behind the scenes!

Comment: As Android Studio comes with JBR (JetBrains Runtime), a bundled JDK basically. The 'jbr' directory contains it. As in the above error it has failed to find the java.exe in jre folder. So he is creating a symbolic link between the two folder using 'mklink', that way when the build process tries to find the java.exe in jre folder, it point to the actual location of the file which is inside the 'jbr' folder. Like a shortcut launcher icon.

Comment: This breaks future patching of Android Studio

Comment: You will not be able to update Android Studio after deleting the jre folder.

Comment: Worked for me on Android Studio Flamingo | 2022.2.1 Patch 1

Answer (score 4):

This is an issue with gradle cache mecanism.

You need to locate `.gradle/daemon/<version>/registry.bin` file and delete it.

*Note: you can delete all the `daemon` sub-folders.*

You can now compile your project with your JAHA_HOME environment variable as Gradle will regenerate those.

Answer (score 2):

THANKS a LOT. You solve my problem. Only to note that you have to remove all the folders inside C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre  by hand

-1. run cmd as administrator

0. *cd "C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio"*
1. remove first files from all subfolders of jre  >  *del /s .\jre*
2. remove jre folder >  *rmdir /s .\jre*
3. make link to jbr folder containing *bin\java.exe* named as jre  > *mklink /D "jre" "jbr"*

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Accepted question will break future Android Studio patch.
Solution for this question is so simple, just delete folder .gradle in your %USER_HOME% (C:/Users/your_user).
Make sure you close Android Studio and all Java.exe process before delete .gradle folder.

Edit:
Upgrade to Flutter 3.7.6 and this bug will be solved.
It can be checked here:
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Hotfixes-to-the-Stable-Channel

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

These two steps were enough for me:

1. Set JAVA_HOME to ...\Android\AndroidStudio\jbr
2. Rename or delete ...\Android\AndroidStudio\jar

Answer (score 0):

Copy everything in the **jbr** folder `C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jbr` than => put it in **jre** folder `C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre` and approve the modification of files.

The above mentioned methods work but prevent android studio from updating.

However, since Android studio **updates** will break the **jre** folder again, if you get an error after the update, you will have to repeat the same process.

Answer (score -1):

1. Delete the folder: `C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre`
2. Restart Android Studio

It solves the issue!